# Searching for keywords in multiple code repositories - Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I was wondering if there is a way to search for keywords in the code through multiple code repositories at once? Preferably I would like to specify a subset of repositories i.e. only those with a marking or organization, and then for a given keyword it would return the matched line together with the source repository and file.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong, it is impossible inside Foundry, but...

I would suggest a workaround.
You could clone the repository locally in your machine and then, opening the synced folders using VS Code, use its search feature, that is able to go through different folders content.

Clone function is available inside each code-repo, and in order to proceed you will need both a git client and VS Code installed locally.

Comment: That was my original thought, however we unfortunately have too many code repositories for this to be practical.